# UITableview NSarray isEqualToString unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to show my records in `UITableview`. I can get the json data. Problem is starting in show them in `UITableViewCell`.

```
-(void)getData {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString;
    dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"tarih":dateString,@"email":@"email@email.com",@"token":@"token",@"id":@"11"};
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://crm.mywebsite.com/api/sync.php"];
    [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&testerror];
        NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
        _customerList = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *customerArray = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"kart"];
        for (NSDictionary *customerDictionary in customerArray) {
            NKart *card = [NKart taskWithTitle:[customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adi"]];
            card.adres = [customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adres"];
            NSLog(@"%@",card.adres);
            [self.customerList addObject:card];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    }];
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
        NKart *card = [_customerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text= card.adi;
```

And I am getting that error when I tried show them in tableview.

```
[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe04b8b5a00
2015-10-16 16:08:25.503 SaphiraCrmm[6271:2023549] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe04b8b5a00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c511f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bf8bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c51a58d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c467f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c467b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010cd3590f -[UITableViewLabel setText:] + 119
    6   SaphiraCrmm                         0x000000010ad24d95 -[CustomerListTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 997
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010ca0d6b3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ca0d7c8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c9e3650 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ca16595 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c9fe9ad -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c96f11c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107c636a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107babd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107baa4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107af1d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107dc9f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001107dd154 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c43d9d7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c43d947 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c43359b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c432e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011027bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c8be676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  SaphiraCrmm                         0x000000010ad297af main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e5f592d start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Adi is not nsarray

There is the json

```
{
                adi = "TestFirm";
                adi2 = "";
                adi3 = "";
                adres = "\U0130STANBUL";
                email = "";
                email2 = "";
                facebook = "";
                fax = "";
                "fk_agent" = 2;
                "fk_faaliyet_alani" = 0;
                "fk_grubu" = 7;
                "fk_il" = 34;
                "fk_kaydi_yapan" = 0;
                "fk_kaynagi" = 0;
                id = 407;
                "kayit_tipi" = 10;
                ktar = "2014-10-30 16:28:00";
                linkedin = "";
                skype = "";
                tel1 = "";
                tel2 = "";
                twitter = "";
                vd = "";
                vn = "";
                www = "";
}
```

So I'am sure its coming string to me.

Comment: It is easy to solve. Try to put breakpoints after you are done with parsing. You will see an array assigned on a string expected object. Also check before you instantiate your cells.

Comment: I already Did that in  
cell.textLabel.text= card.adi; 
its crashing.

Comment: Something must be wrong with card.adi

Comment: what is adi ? Where is it declared ? Is it an array or a string ?

Comment: its actually name.And I declared in nsobject class in Nkart.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *adi;

Comment: Replace your misuse of `valueForKey:` with calls to `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, logs says it all - the object you think is of type `NSString` is really `NSArray`. Since, `NSArray` does not respond to any method called `isEqualToString`, it crashes!

Here is what might be happening:

Check out your `NKart` model setting. Although, you have declared `adi` as `NSString`, you are actually type casting `NSArray` to `NSString`. Apparently you are getting an `NSArray` and when you set this object to your label's text property, something goes on behind the scenes to ask if the current string property is equal to the one you're trying to set. This results into crash!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an `NSArray`, rather than an `NSString`, here:

```
NKart *card = [NKart taskWithTitle:[customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adi"]];
```

You need to double-check the incoming JSON, but it's certainly an array, not a string.

You probably want:

```
NSArray *adi = customerDictionary[@"adi"];
if ([adi count] > 0) {
    NKart *card = [NKart taskWithTitle:adi[0]];
    ...
}
```

Although I don't know *exactly* what's required; only you do.

Answer (score 0):

**isEqualToString** method remains in **NSString** class. but this  method not exist for **NSArray** Class.

provide value of

```
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
```

to solve  your issue quickly.

**2nd attempt:** you code remain some unnecessary code.

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&testerror];
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
_customerList = [NSMutableArray array];
//NSArray *customerArray = [_customerList addObject:[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"kart"]];
//for (NSDictionary *customerDictionary in customerArray) {
    NKart *card = [NKart taskWithTitle:[customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adi"]];
    card.adres = [customerDictionary valueForKey:@"adres"];
    NSLog(@"%@",card.adres);
    [self.customerList addObject:card];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
//}
```

Comment: Actually I editted to my question and added the json.So That is the log result of the dataDictionary.

Comment: json return once? or json returns frequenly?